# How to make WPF track changes of an extended partial objectEntity. with a custom property

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, partial-classes

I have a Class called Person which has the properties Name and Lastname. I have created a partial class Person which extends the EF generated one with a FullName property. In a certain moment I need to generate the Fullname. The fullname is binded to a control so it can be shown. If I change the fullname property, the wpf control does not get updated.

I know that I have to extend the propery to trigger an event on changing, but I never done this before.

Also, I know that this could be done with stringformating, but this is a simplification of my problem.

Comment: found it. i think.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039513/how-can-i-get-my-partial-class-to-update

Answer (score 0):

Creating and registering a dependency property is probably what you are looking to do.

```
public class MyStateControl : ButtonBase
{
  public MyStateControl() : base() { }
  public Boolean State
  {
   get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(StateProperty); }
   set { this.SetValue(StateProperty, value); } `enter code here`
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
   "State", typeof(Boolean), typeof(MyStateControl),new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

[DependencyProperty Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx)

Comment: as far as I see, this should be working, but the downside to a solution like this is that I need to inherit base controls, what in my opinion is not good, because very soon you'll be having a lot of those for different kinds of controls.

Comment: The solution I found (link in the comment of my problem) is to trigger the OnPropertyChanged event. Works like a charm. I needed 3 lines of code in one class and it works anywhere